# Android - Decoding h264 raw stream manually

Tags: android, video, h.264, decoder

So I am trying to decode a stream of raw h264 data and render it to a surface on Android. Here are the steps:

1. Receive a packet of h264 stream
2. Accumulate it and try to extract NAL units (byte sequences starting with **00 00 00 01** (NAL header) and up until the next NAL header.
3. For every extracted NAL unit, call feedFrame(data) where data is a byte[] that starts with NAL header and contains the extracted unit.
4. See the video rendered on the surface I provided.

The following code does utilizes the AVC decoder:

```
public StreamReceiver(DashCamActivity activity, Surface surface, int width, int height, byte[] sps, byte[] pps) {
    this.activity = activity;
    decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");

    format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(sps));
    format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(pps));
    decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
    decoder.start();

}

public void shutdown() 
{
    decoder.stop();
    decoder.release();
}

public void feedFrame(byte[] data) 
{
    BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
    int inputIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1000);
    if(inputIndex == -1)
        return;
    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = decoder.getInputBuffers()[inputIndex];
    if (inputIndex >= 0) {
        inputBuffer.clear();
        inputBuffer.put(data, 0, data.length);
        inputBuffer.clear();
        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, data.length, 0, 0);
    }

    int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 1000);

    switch (outIndex) {
    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
        break;

    case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
        break;

    case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
        break;

    default:
        decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
        break;
    }
}
```

For smaller resolutions (1024x768, 1280x800) everything works perfectly. However with larger resolutions (1920x1080, 1900x600), where the length of the byte array I provide is above 65535 (64k), the video starts having stutters and artifacts and Logcat reports strange decoder errors (e.g. IOCTL_MFC_DEC_EXE failed(ret : -2001) on Galaxy S3).
This also happens on a relatively new device that can play 4k with twice the framerate I provide. So I must be doing something wrong, and I don't know if my 64k theory has any truth in it, it's merely an observation.

So to recap:

- I am providing individual NAL units to the decoder, starting with the
  header.
- The h264 stream is of baseline profile, level 4.0.
- Writing the contents of the NAL units to a file in the order they arrive produces a video file that is fully playable using the basic media players

How do I get it to play at high resolutions?

Comment: Well, you're only giving it 1000us to decode a frame. If the frame isn't ready by then, do you have sufficient logic in place to execute a re-try, or do frames just start queuing up in the decoder?

Comment: There is no retry logic since I don't know if a frame is to be decoded after a given moment. A frame consists of unknown number of NALs. I don't now where a new frame starts and I have no choice but to simply feed them and hope video comes out

Comment: Seems to me your choice of architecture has left you with a number of unhandled edge cases (that are exacerbated by higher resolutions). Why don't you switch the codec to asynchronous operation? Saves you from having to block for N microseconds when trying to dequeue an output buffer. You'll have to rethink how you queue input buffers, though.